# Show selected row always while scrolling UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, twitter, scroll

Let's say we have a UITableView with some 100 rows, we select a row and after that we scroll the UITableView. The selected row is also scrolled top or bottom direction but I want the selected row to be always visible to the user while scrolling the table. Is it possible ?? please help me out which sample code..(it is same like twitter scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this, you'll have to write a completely custom tableview from scratch (which I believe was done for Twitter.app). There's no way to do that with the built-in tableview.